# Django forms with stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, stored-procedures, django-forms

I am trying to invoke a stored procedure within a django form. This will fill a select in the template. Apparently it can be called with cursor.execute (), but I can't get it to work.

I leave part of the code:

```
class FormX(forms.ModelForm):
    fieldX = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table'), required=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) performing raw queries
And [another one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) for directly use

If you wanna use cursor

```
from django.db import connection

    def my_custom_sql(self):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
            row = cursor.fetchall()
        return row
```

Comment: Thanks, its work. `from django.db import connection cursor = connection.cursor(); cursor.execute('call spProcedure(%s)', [request.POST['param']] )`